# elsarticle: Line number stopped in middle of document

Tags: line-numbering, elsarticle

I'm using `\modulolinenumbers[5]` and document class `elsarticle`.

**Line numbers** worked fine till page 6 it stopped working to page 10 then it came back continuing from the number it stopped at.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

*Code edit suggestion by Manuel Kuehner*

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\begin{document}

\section{SectionA}                     
Counting here works fine            

\begin{figure} [ht]                                                                         
\subfloat[][Manual annotation]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:Annotation}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][EDF image]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:EDF_image}}                                                         \caption{}                                                                                       
\end{figure}                                                                                    

\section{SectionB}                                                                         

Line counting here doesn't appear  

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Can you add a minimal working example? = can you add your minimal code, please?

Comment: `\section{SectionA}` First paragraph that include inline equation `$0.1e^-3`    then `\begin{figure}`     subfigures    `\end{figure}`  then another section `\section{SectionB}` Here counting stopped

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: @Sebastiano thanks, I edited the question to have the minimal code. thanks for your help.

Comment: The code is badly formatted, please revise it. Copy it from your source, paste it in the editing box, select it and click on the small `{}` icon.

Comment: @Sebastiano No, now it's even worse.

Comment: @egreg I have not seen. Rollback the original code. I have removed my previous comment. Excuse me.

Comment: Is your problem still active?

Answer (score 4):

- I cleaned up your code and with "my" result, I do not see any problem so far.
- A `\linenumbers` (from the `lineno` package) was missing in my opinion.
- There was an open `\begin{fromtmatter}` without a corresponding `\end`. I assume this is due to a "lazy" [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228) (`-->` please test your own code before posting it).

---

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\linenumbers % <-- added

\usepackage{blindtext} % <-- added

\begin{document}

\section{SectionA}                     
Counting here works fine.  

\blindtext % <-- added          

\begin{figure}[ht]                                                                         
\subfloat[][Manual annotation]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-a}\label{fig:Annotation}}
\qquad
\subfloat[][EDF image]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{example-image-b}\label{fig:EDF_image}}                                                         \caption{}                                                                                       
\end{figure}                                                                                    

\section{SectionB}                                                                         

Line counting here doesn't appear. % <-- Yes, it does :). 

\blindtext % <-- added   

\end{document}
```

[image]